# Are there any tools for working with PL/SQL?

Tags: software-recommendation, oracle, sql

I am currently using Oracle SQL Developer, and it is driving me nuts.

I keep getting the message `Connection is busy` when trying to anything after being inactive in some minutes. Sometimes pressing `ctrl + shift + n` does the trick, but other times it won't do.

Other times the graphics in text components get distorted. I'm using Sun's JDK (6).

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: What version of SQL Developer do you use? [There's](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1030145&tstart=0&start=15) a thread were an Oracle employee recommends 3.0 EA1. Otherwise you could try [Tora](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1030145&tstart=0&start=15).

Comment: I use 3.0 already. Also, both your links point to the same URL. :)

Comment: Oops, the link to Tora should have been [this one](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/tora).

Comment: You might apply fix sql database http://www.fixsqldatabase.com makes the work with sql data pleasure, owns advanced suite of features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you absolutely must use Oracle's product, there are many combinations of programming language and database engine that will probably meet your needs. Surely if you are already using Java you could just program your logic in that language and make your queries against a Postgres database, for example.

I apologize if I've misunderstood your question. If you necessarily must use PL/SQL then there is a list of possible alternatives [at alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/pl-sql-developer/). Unfortunately I don't see anything in that list that looks likely to meet your needs apart from [Toad For Oracle](http://www.toadworld.com/ORACLE/tabid/758/Default.aspx), which is apparently a non-free product.

Comment: I'm having an exam in PL/SQL (unfortunately), so I'm bound to use PL/SQL.